# Regular expression not matching string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out the following regular expression:

```
/^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2,3}[a-zA-z]{0,1}/g
```

In my example.
The following should pass: 00-45, 00-333, 33-333a, 55-34a
The following should fail: 33-3333, 22-22dd, 22-2233

Here is my screenshot:

[image]

But the once that should fail arent failing.  In my javascript code I just do a test:

```
var regExp = new RegExp(exp);
if(regExp.test(test1))
    alert('pass');
else
    alert('fail');
```

Is there a way for the regular expression to test the entire string?  Example 33-3333 passes because of 33-333, but since there is another 3 I would like it to fail since the fourth 3 would be tested against the character rule?

Comment: use `^` and `$` to indicate line beginning and ending

Comment: Did you forget glob? - `new RegExp(exp, 'g');` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are missing end anchor `$` in your input
2. `A-z` inside character class will match unwanted characters as well, you actually need `A-Z`
3. `{0,1}` can be shortened to `?`

Try this regex:

```
/^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2,3}[a-zA-Z]?$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bN4iW2/1)

Comment: You are so speed. :)

Comment: Thanks all, it seems like I forgot the $.  I do like your shorter version of removing the last {0,1} for just ?